# Adding elements on many-to-many relation

Tags: swift, core-data, nsset

I am making a project where (from the perspective of school) you can calculate each student average.
You can register a student (first entity) on a screen and subjects (second entity) on another screen.
Student has name, email, grade and average as atributes, and Subjects has name. They relate many-to-many with each other.

I am trying to create a copy of subjects list to each student, then on each student i can register a grade to each subject. Like this:

[Model concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6Ihu.png)

Model:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/JipWz.jpg

I've created a singleton of subjects since it is used more than one location:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class SubjectsManager {
    static let shared = SubjectsManager()
    var subjects: [Subject] = []

    func loadSubject(with context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Subject> = Subject.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescritor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescritor]

        do {
            subjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func deleteSubject(index: Int, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let subject = subjects[index]
        context.delete(subject)

        do {
            try context.save()
            subjects.remove(at: index)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    private init() {

    }
}
```

And, on my student screen, i've tried many thing but nothing is working.
The to-many relation of student with subject is called `registeredSubjects`
I've created a NSSET called `subjectsManagerSet` to get values from the singleton, but it not working. Here what i've tried so far:

```
subjectManagerSet.addingObjects(from: subjectsManager.subjects)
```

Also tried to create a for loop of `subjectManager.subjects` to add on `subjectManagerSet` but it's not working too.

About errors, when i get samples from xcode output, it keep showing that `subjectManagerSet` did not get values from `subjectManager.subject`

Error message:

```
2019-09-26 20:38:16.983725-0300 MyAverage[1734:62290] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/vitorgomes/Desktop/Mentorizacao/MyAverage/MyAverage/Controllers/StudentsViewController.swift, line 119
(lldb) po subjectManagerSet
0 elements
```

The expected result is that i want a copy of subjects for each student instance, then i can add grades for each subjects for each student.

Comment: virtu can you screenshot or copy and paste into your question, the code on line 119 of your StudentsViewController.swift file (per error message)?

Answer (score 1):

> The expected result is that i want a copy of subjects for each student
>   instance, then i can add grades for each subjects for each student.

I am not addressing your problem as stated at the beginning of your question, but the one stated at the end, per the quote above.

I would encourage you to reconsider the structure of your model.

Perhaps something like this?

[image: proposed Core Data object model graph]

In this proposed model, you're able to assign to an object of the entity `Enrolment`:

- a `grade` (and `date`) via these attribute properties;
- a student via the one-to-many relationship property with a `Student` entity;
- a subject via the one-to-many relationship property with a `Subject` entity.

In the following examples, I assume Core Data generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses - that is - in the Data Model Inspector, set the value for Codegen = Class Definition (default).

(Personally and as an aside, I prefer to manually write `NSManagedObject` subclasses for each of my entities and use `Set` rather than the  `NSSet`, as I find it subsequently a lot easier to maintain type integrity in my code. But I have not done that here as most people who are new to Core Data will use the default for Codegen noted above.)

You're able to access these values in the following manner...

```
    let student = Student()

    print("Student name is: \(String(describing: student.name))")

    if let studentEnrolments: NSSet = student.studentEnrolments {

        for item in studentEnrolments {

            if
                let enrolment = item as? Enrolment,
                let subjectName: String = enrolment.subject?.name {

                print("Subject name for this student is: \(subjectName)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Its easy to assign a subject enrolment to a student...

```
    let enrolment = Enrolment()
    let subject = Subject()

    enrolment.subject = subject

    student.addToStudentEnrolments(enrolment)
```

Then now or later, a grade can be applied to the enrolled subject...

```
    let grade: String = "A"

    enrolment.grade = grade
```

Of course the average becomes a mathematical function based on the sum of all grades for each student, divided by the count. This is in my humble opinion, better constructed as it is needed, rather than saved as an attribute with each `Student` object.

**Update**

Im updating my answer to include a little database theory to explain my proposed object model.

According to Wikipedia, [Database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is...

> the process of structuring a relational database
>   in accordance with a series of so-called normal forms in order to
>   reduce data redundancy and improve data integrity.

What does this practically mean to me? It means breaking my data down into its most discrete and unique parts, so that, in theory, I never need to enter any unique piece of data more than once.

Let me use a simple table example as a means of explaining this, as it might be set out in a spreadsheet (or your model concept):

*Original Data*

```
     TABLE 1
     A          B           C
1    STUDENT    SUBJECT     GRADE    
2    Student1   Mathematics 8.8
3    Student1   Physics     7.0
4    Student1   Biology     6.0
5    Student2   Mathematics 5.0
6    Student2   Physics     9.0
7    Student2   Biology     7.0
```

*Normalised Data*

```
     TABLE 1                             TABLE 2              TABLE 3
     A          B           C            A     B              A     B
1    STUDENT    SUBJECT     GRADE        ID    STUDENT        ID    SUBJECT
2    1          1           8.8          1     Student1       1     Mathematics
3    1          2           7.0          2     Student2       2     Physics
4    1          3           6.0                               3     Biology
5    2          1           5.0
6    2          2           9.0
7    2          3           7.0
```

The normalised data uses *relationships* between the three tables. It stores the `ID` (as a primary key) of each `STUDENT` and each `SUBJECT`, instead of the actual words. This is obviously far more efficient in many different ways, including but not limited to: bytes of stored data, ability to index, speed of data retrieval.

When you set a *relationship* property in your Core Data object model graph, you are doing the same thing...

So for your example, the Core Data object model graph **Entity** replaces TABLE. The Core Data framework automagically inserts a primary key column into the SQLite database for us when it constructs the tables and later a primary key unique integer when we programmatically add rows (records, a.k.a instances of an entity). While we don't have direct access to that as a developer (using Core Data), the Core Data framework allows us to build one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many **relationships** between two entities, that achieves the same outcome.

```
     Enrolment                           Student              Subject
     A          B           C            A     B              A     B
     Rel.       Rel.        Att.         Rel.  Att.           Rel.  Att.
     ∞          ∞                        1                    1
Z_PK Student    Subject     grade        Z_PK  name           Z_PK  name
1    1          1           8.8          1     Student1       1     Mathematics
2    1          2           7.0          2     Student2       2     Physics
3    1          3           6.0                               3     Biology
4    2          1           5.0
5    2          2           9.0
6    2          3           7.0
```

`Att.` = Entity **Attribute**;

`Rel.` = Entity **Relationship**;

`∞` = many side of one-to-many **Relationship** (<<-);

`1` = one side of one-to-many **Relationship** (-->)

---

Any questions, let me know?

Comment: So, basically enrollment is a join table between students and subjects right?
I saw something on Apple's documentation that when you create a many-to-many relation it automatically creates a join table to you, but, i dont know if i missed the next part but it was not explaining more about this automatic join table. I was hunting this on many documentations and did not find it.
I will try your suggestion when i arrive home, now i am using windows at work.

Comment: Just to explain better the quote, i made a drawing of it:

https://imgur.com/ymema8J

This is how i am planning the app. Each student should have a copy of subjects, then these students can register their grades for each student entry.

Comment: I'm sorry you have to use Windows

Comment: It is not really a join table... a join table is, as you mention in your comment, created in the SQLite database by the Core Data framework for many-to-many relationships. If you open your SQLite db using Terminal, you can see these via the command `.schema`. What I'm suggesting is a theoretical adjustment in your model... I'll update my answer to better explain.

Comment: PS: I suggest that you edit your question to add/include your drawing. It clearly explains what you want to achieve and will help others a lot when they are either attempting to provide their own answer (perhaps better than mine) or searching for a solution to their own problem. Worth noting that some users don't read the comments. It also ensures all information relevant to your question is in one place, making it easier for users to understand the entire context.

Comment: Also don't forget to edit your question and add line 119 of your StudentsViewController.swift file (per the error message).

Comment: `extension StudentsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return student.registeredSubjects?.count ?? 0
    }`

I know why is wrong, the relation is still empty even receiving subjectManagerSet (that is also still empyt)

Comment: Somehow, my enrolment is still getting nil value, even assigning objects to it. I made a modification on your code to adapt to my, but it seems it still not assigning:


 `           for subject in subjectsManager.subjects {
                enrolment.subject = subject
                student.addToStudentEnrolments(enrolment)
            }`

`subjectsManager.subjects` is the instance of the singleton i've created for subjects.

Comment: somehow on the "You're able to access these values in the following manner..." part it is showing a single element of the nsset:

'if let studentEnrolments: NSSet = student.studentEnrolments {

            for item in studentEnrolments {

                if let enrolment = item as? Enrolment, let subjectName: String = enrolment.subject?.name {

                    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(subjectName)"
                    
                    //print("Subject name for this student is: \(subjectName)")
                }
            }
        }'
Do you know why?

Comment: Are you still attempting to do all this using the `SubjectManager` class?

Comment: yes, i am still using the singleton SubjectManager, it is only for register and delete subjects. I've registered there two subjects as sample, but when i do some tests here using the access you gave in the beggining, it is showing a single subject, duplicated.

Comment: On my register button, i adapted the code you provided to the app, i run all my subjectManager subjects registered then i put on enrolment:

Comment: 'if student == nil {
            student = Student(context: context)
            enrolment = Enrolment(context: context)
            
            for subject in subjectsManager.subjects {
                enrolment.subject = subject
                student.addToStudentEnrolments(enrolment)
                print("student registered on subject: \(enrolment.subject?.name) com nota \(enrolment.grade)")
            }
        }
'