# Running objects from a NSSET

Tags: swift, core-data, nsset

I am trying to run all the objects from a NSSET i have, but somehow it is getting just one.
Based on my previous problem ([Adding elements on many-to-many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58126027/adding-elements-on-many-to-many-relation))

This is how i am trying to get:

```
if let studentEnrolments: NSSet = student.studentEnrolments {

  for item in studentEnrolments {

     if let enrolment = item as? Enrolment, let subjectName: String = enrolment.subject?.name {

       cell.textLabel?.text = "\(subjectName)"
     }
  }
}
```

After that i show the object name on a cell from my tableView.
For explanation, my project has three entities on coremodel:

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBpnt.png)

My subjects are collected by a singleton called subjectsManager who feed the enrolment, like this:

```
for subject in subjectsManager.subjects {
   enrolment.subject = subject
   student.addToStudentEnrolments(enrolment)
}
```

I can see that everytime i register a new student, it is adding subjects to the student correctly, but somehow when i try to show the registered subjects using the first loop, it is showing repetly a single subject twice.

This is the subject manager class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

    class SubjectsManager {
        static let shared = SubjectsManager()
        var subjects: [Subject] = []

        func loadSubject(with context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Subject> = Subject.fetchRequest()
            let sortDescritor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescritor]

            do {
                subjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        func deleteSubject(index: Int, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
            let subject = subjects[index]
            context.delete(subject)

            do {
                try context.save()
                subjects.remove(at: index)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        private init() {

        }
    }
```

And this is the view where i register/update students:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class StudentsViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var tfName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tfEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbAverage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tvSubjects: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbTableTittle: UILabel!

    // MARK: - Variables and Constants

    var student: Student!
    var enrolment: Enrolment!
    var subjectsManager = SubjectsManager.shared
    var total: Double = 0.0
    var average: Double = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let student = student {
            navigationItem.title = student.name
            tfName.text = student.name
            tfEmail.text = student.email
            lbTableTittle.text = "Subjects and grades of \(student.name!)"
            if let studentEnrolments: NSSet = student.studentEnrolments {

                for item in studentEnrolments {

                    if let enrolment = item as? Enrolment, let subjectGrade: Double = enrolment.grade {

                        total += enrolment.grade
                    }
                }
            }
            average = total / Double(subjectsManager.subjects.count)
            lbAverage.text = String(average)
        } else {
            navigationItem.title = "new student"
            lbTableTittle.text = "Non registred student"
            lbAverage.text = "Student doenst has average yet"
        }
        subjectsManager.loadSubject(with: context)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tvSubjects.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func addEditStudent(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if student == nil {
            student = Student(context: context)
            enrolment = Enrolment(context: context)

            for subject in subjectsManager.subjects {
                enrolment.subject = subject
                //enrolment.grade = 0.0
                student.addToStudentEnrolments(enrolment)
                print("student registred on subject: \(enrolment.subject?.name) with grade \(enrolment.grade)")
            }
        }

        student.name = tfName.text
        student.email = tfEmail.text

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }

}

// MARK: - Extensions

extension StudentsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return student != nil ? subjectsManager.subjects.count : 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tvSubjects.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        if let studentEnrolments: NSSet = student.studentEnrolments {

            for item in studentEnrolments {

                if let enrolment = item as? Enrolment, let subjectName: String = enrolment.subject?.name {

                    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(subjectName)"
                }
            }
        }


        return cell
    }



extension StudentsViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

Comment: It feels like a scope issue with your variables, but without the method signatures and type/variable definitions it's hard to be sure.  Are you able to update your question with all the relevant code rather than just snippets?  (for example, we don't know what type student.studentEnrollments in the top snippet are, or what enrolment is in the lower code)

Comment: @flanker ok, i just added some more code. The only one missing is the student view, but this view only shows the students names and averages (average still not fully implemented).