# Displaying NSSET data on tableView

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, nsset

I am trying to populate an embed tableView on a ViewController that i've created with some data from CoreData.

My project is about a School app where i can register students and subjects. This is how model was designed:

[Core Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JExQp.png)

Students are added when i create a new entry, normal method:

```
@IBAction func addEditStudent(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if student == nil {
            student = Student(context: context)
            enrolment = Enrolment(context: context)

            for subject in subjectsManager.subjects {
                enrolment.subject = subject
                student.addToStudentEnrolments(enrolment)
            }
        }

        student.name = tfName.text
        student.email = tfEmail.text

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
```

You can also see how enrolments are registered on the "for subject" loop on the same code above.

Now, for Subjects i've created a singleton for it:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class SubjectsManager {
    static let shared = SubjectsManager()
    var subjects: [Subject] = []

    func loadSubject(with context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Subject> = Subject.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescritor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescritor]

        do {
            subjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func deleteSubject(index: Int, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let subject = subjects[index]
        context.delete(subject)

        do {
            try context.save()
            subjects.remove(at: index)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    private init() {

    }
}
```

Now, this is where my problem is, when trying to populate a tableView (after student is created), it is not showing properly.
I tried to methods to do this but it is not working, first one is from a same article i created where a guy from here helped me:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tvSubjects.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if let studentEnrolments: NSSet = student.studentEnrolments {

            for item in studentEnrolments {

                if
                    let enrolment = item as? Enrolment,
                    let subjectName: String = enrolment.subject?.name {

                    print("Subject name for this student is: \(subjectName)")
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

On this way, for example if i have two subjects registered it shoes two entries but a copied result (2x the first item of the singleton). I guess this is missing the indexpath.row, but i've tried many ways and still not working.

Now this is the second option i am trying but it keep showing errors before i compile it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tvSubjects.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    if let _ = student.studentEnrolments {
        let itemsOnListArray = student.studentEnrolments!.allObjects
    }
    let item = itemsOnListArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item as? String
    return cell
}
```

Using this, i am getting error message "Use of unresolved identifier 'itemsOnListArray'" on `let item = itemsOnListArray[indexPath.row]` line

Please, let me know if you need some more code parts but i think this is all the important parts from my project.
PS: tableView methods are from extensions parts for UITableViewDataSource, since this tableView is embed on ViewController.

Comment: How many enrolments are created and added to the student?

Comment: @Willeke, i am using a single enrolment to register all subjects from the subjectManager to each student, like on this previous for i posted:

`for subject in subjectsManager.subjects {
                enrolment.subject = subject
                student.addToStudentEnrolments(enrolment)
            }`
I took this from the past question i made here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58126027/adding-elements-on-many-to-many-relation

Comment: `enrolment.subject = subject` sets or replaces the subject, it doesn't add a subject. Create a new enrolment for each subject inside the for loop.

Comment: @Willeke, i think i got what you said, so in this loop everytime it runs, it is setting the same value? How can i create a enrolment for each subject?